# ActionScript 2: tracing contents of a global class

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

The files I'm using have been decompiled from a game using scaleform and can only be tested inside the engine.

I would like to know all the functions of "_global.GameInterface"

Is it possible to iter through each line of a referenced class and output to a textbox?

Comment: Does said game's license permit you to decompile it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_global.GameInterface is not a Flash standard variable, so it something the game developers created. Most likely it is not a Class, but rather just an Object. I believe a for(prop in object) loop will iterate over all the properties of the object.

For example:

```
for (var prop in _global.GameInterface) {
    trace(this[prop]);
}
```